# Spring-Boot-Actuator : Aggregation of /health endpoints cross micro-services

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

In our micro-services based architecture we want to have a single health output/view for all the micro-services comprising one application.

One of the ways could be to create another application that connects to /health endpoints of all configured micro-services, aggregate the responses (JSON's), and display status for the over-all application and its individual micro-services' health.

But given, every micro-service may emit a different set of contents and metrics in the health status, it might need some customisation for each health end-points, and that may not be the best way to achieve it IMO.

Going with how Hystrix-Turbine project helps one aggregate and display single view for Hystrix metrics for my cluster, is there a project available or pipe-lined to have similar capability made available with Spring-Boot-Actuators?

Thanks in adv for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Josh Long's Spring Tips video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1QnlAbCFys&index=9&list=PLgGXSWYM2FpPw8rV0tZoMiJYSCiLhPnOc

It has showed how can it be done using the Spring-Boot-Admin work from Codecentric project.

Below links will be of more help:

1. Link to the Spring Boot Admin Project: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin
2. And the Getting Started Guide: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.4/#getting-started﻿

The video also gave a pointer on how to visualise your micro-services architecture with mapped view of Resource, Services and Backend system, using microservices-dashboard-server work from project Ordina.

These are surely not the only options but are pretty easy and cheap to use for case.